# Is there any way to run executable programs on windows in ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I have a dual boot system comprising of u untu 14.04 and windows. Now when I log into Ubuntu I have access to my windows files and folders as well. Some of the files like documents and images work well, but the executable programs cannot be run. Is there any way to run these files? Do I have to install or download some special progrmas to convert these files and make them compatible for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The most common tool to do so is [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) (stands for **W**ine  **i**s **n**ot an **e**mulator). Wine takes windows programs and basically "translates" the Windows commands to Linux commands in real time.

Wine can be installed via the official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

However, I prefer using PlayOnLinux. This is a graphical frontend and manager for Wine. It supports multiple virtual drives, one for each Windows program, so they won't interfere with each other. Additionally, PlayOnLinux supports multiple Wine versions. For each application, you can choose the best-working version. And for many programs there's an installation script which does all the work for you.

Install PlayOnLinux using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```